# How to get back stolen tokens from the exchange?

Tags: tokens, phishing

so recently i got stolen in about 50k in Humaniq tokens .. it was a phishing website directed from a slack DM E-mail .. so the guy who stole them,has also stole a lot from other people but everything that comes in never comes out of his wallet and people are reporting his address .. HMQ(Humaniq tokens) are only on 3 or maybe 4 exchanges so only 4 ways to go. Is there any possibility to get my tokens back if i try communicating with exchanges and prove that this stolen fund belongs to me . Thank you

Comment: Here is the site that just stole my tokens
[url removed]. Address sent to
Address: 0x1f7869c802B9eB942a1D884F1A38127F928915d2

Comment: Hi there. I'm sorry to hear about your problem. Please don't post URLs that have been involved in phishing attacks. The more instances of this URL that exist, the more chances there are that other people will (perhaps accidentally) click on it. I've edited your post to remove it. Also, this isn't an answer to the question, so I've flagged it as such I'm afraid.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11096)

Answer (score 1):

What you need to remember is that exchanges tend to be run as for profit businesses.

You are correct to say that to sell the tokens the scammer will likely have to use one of these exchanges. If they do, then yes perhaps the exchanges will be able to 'lock' the stolen tokens.

That said, it may be cost prohibitive for them to discern to whom the tokens actually belong, and as such unless you make it worth their while they will likely not want to put in the effort to help you.

Sorry to be the bearer of bad news.